# OrderItem doesn't have a recordtype, so how can use different page layouts depending on Order rectype?

Tags: page-layout, record-type, order, orderitem

I have different recordtypes for the Order object, and the line items (OrderItem) need to show different fields depending on the Order recordtype, yet I can't seem to do this. It allows me to create different page layouts for the OrderItem, but how can I choose which OrderItem layout to display depending on the Order recordtype?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the present time --  recordtypes on Order Product (`OrderItem`). Nor is it available on `QuoteItem` or `OpportunityLineItem`

What SFDC is trying to get you to do is avoid the overloading of the line item SObject with multiple meanings and custom fields for various flavors.

The line items are supposed to be SKU (product code) - quantity - price.  What makes one line item different from another is the SKU.  Hence think of the `Product2` as the way to flavor your line item with different characteristics.

For example, fields on `Product2` like `Is Returnable?` or `Is Refundable?` or `Is Fulfilled by`. These can be used to in reporting on line items w/ products as well as in any apex or formula logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach `Order RecordType` and click on `Page Layout Assignment` button.

[image: order recordtype]

It will open this page

[image: Edit Assignment]

Now click on Edit Assignment and assign the page layout respective to profiles.

[image: Assign Page Layout]

Comment: Hi Santanu - I need a different page layout for the OrderItem, depending on the Order. I already have different record types for the Orders, and a page layout for each, but they all use the same OrderItem layout, and that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: Yes, we cannot manage different layouts based on recordtypes for order lineitems, only we can change the order layouts